# Strict inequality logical implication in optimization problems

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, integer-programming, constraints, mixed-integer-programming

I have $ x \in \{0,1\}$ and $y \geq 0$ and I want to model that $x=1$ iff $y>0$, is this possible while keeping the constraint linear? Thanks.

One part of the implication is easy $ y \leq Mx$. The other part I can approximate as $ \epsilon x \leq y $. Where $\epsilon$ is small and $M$ is big. But this doesn't work if $y$ is very small.

Comment: Your constraint handles $y>0\implies x=1$. To handle the reverse case, you want $x=1$ to be less optimal than $x=0$ when $y=0$. You can handle this by adjusting the objective function by $-Mx$ (in the case of maximisation), as it will force $x=0$ unless it is required to be positive at the optimal solution.

Comment: thanks, there's no other way?

Comment: As you’ve observed, trying to put an upper bound on $x$ changes the range of values available for $y$. I don’t have all of my literature available to check at the moment, but the method I described is my usual approach when the remainder of the problem is linear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In practice, if $y$ is computed (as opposed to a parameter that is read in and never changed), the chances are high that you will get a nonzero value (possibly even negative) when it should be zero, due to rounding error. Constraints aside, you probably should set a tolerance value $\epsilon > 0$, small but not too small, and round $y$ to $0$ any time $|y|<\epsilon$. That will let you proceed as you proposed in your question.

Answer (score 0):

> Your constraint handles y>0⟹x=1. To handle the reverse case, you want
>   x=1 to be less optimal than x=0 when y=0. You can handle this by
>   adjusting the objective function by −Mx (in the case of maximisation),
>   as it will force x=0 unless it is required to be positive at the
>   optimal solution. – Daryl